# How can I check date and time on javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime, timezone

My script like this :

```
function checkDatetime() {
    const e = new Date((new Date).toLocaleString("en-US", {
        timeZone: "Asia/Jakarta"
    }));
    return e.getDay() >= 1 && e.getDay() <= 5 && e.getHours() >= 8 && e.getHours() < 17
}
```

if checkDatetime return true, it will show message "Available"

if checkDatetime return false, it will show message "Not Available"

I had testing it and it works. My position at jakarta(indonesia)

But there are people who call the function at 18:20 and 22:22 and it show "Available'

Should it show "Not available"

Is this a timezone problem?

**Update** :

Another solution from me :

```
function checkDatetime() {
  const offsetHours = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
  const day = new Date();

  day.setHours(day.getHours() + offsetHours);

  return day.getDay() >= 1 && day.getDay() <= 5 && day.getHours() >= 1 && day.getHours() < 10;
}
```

Comment: The update (unreliably) shifts the time by the local offset so is effectively UTC. You could do the same by just using *getUTCDay* and *getUTCHours*. The value supplied to *setHours* should be in an integer, fractional values are truncated to the integer part. Since many places have an offset that is not an even number of hours (e.g. parts of India and central Australia), your adjustment won't be consistent for them (even if it was useful).

Comment: @RobG so my second script isn't effective to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a fundamental misunderstanding of ECMAScript Date objects. They are just an offset from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z and have no other associated data such as timezone or offset.

The expression:

```
new Date((new Date).toLocaleString("en-US", {
    timeZone: "Asia/Jakarta"
}));
```

`(new Date)` creates a date for the current time, calling *toLocaleString* with options produces a timestamp for the current date and time for location "Asia/Jakarta".

That is then parsed by the enclosing call to the Date constructor to produce a Date for the same instant in time. If the string produced includes the timezone name or offset for "Asia/Jakarta" (which it may or may not as it's implementation dependent) it's the same as:

```
 new Date();
```

So *getDay* returns the day for the local timezone, not "Asia/Jakarta". Note also that the built–in parser may not correctly parse the string returned by *toLocaleString*, especially where options have been used.

If you want to use built–in methods, consider the [Intl.DateTimeFormat constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) and the [*formatToParts* method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts). That will return string values for the date and time parts for a particular representative location like "Asia/Jakarta". You can then do things with the parts as you would with Date methods.

Note that some of the date parts have different names to the related date methods, also the day names are returned rather than numbers.

```js
function checkDatetime(loc) {
  let f = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {
    year    : 'numeric',
    month   : '2-digit',
    day     : '2-digit',
    weekday : 'short',
    hour    : '2-digit',
    hour12  :  false,
    minute  : '2-digit',
    second  : '2-digit',
    timeZone: loc
  });
  let temp = f.formatToParts(new Date());
  let parts = temp.reduce((acc, part) => {
    if (part.type != 'literal') {
      acc[part.type] = part.value;
    }
    return acc;
  }, Object.create(null));
  
  // Debug
  console.log(parts);
  
  return parts.weekday != 'Sat' && parts.weekday != 'Sun' &&
         parts.hour >= 8 && parts.hour < 17;
}

console.log(checkDatetime('Asia/Jakarta'));
```

Comment: Okay thanks. I will try your code. I have a simpler code. see my question. I update the answer with my answer. What's your opinion?

Comment: I am still trying your code. if it works, I will accept your answer

Comment: I have implemented your code on my production website. But there are some users who can enter. Does your code run in all browsers? it seems that in certain browsers it doesn't work

Comment: @positivethinking—define "doesn't work". I've tested it in recent versions of Safari, Opera, Firefox and Chrome. Some of your users may have older browsers that don't support the timezone option, which is why this kind of calculation should be done on the server where you know the code will run correctly.

Comment: I mean there are some users who can login above 17.00. for example at 19:30. So your code doesn't work in an old browser version? Does your code work in all zones?

Comment: @positivethinking—this **must not** be used to control whether a user can log in, as users can simply change their system clock and the function will think it's a different time. It should be used for information purposes only. Yes, there are older implementations that do not support the required features such as *timeZone* and *formatToParts*.

Comment: Okay. What do you think is the right solution for this problem?

Comment: What is the best solution I do double check. Check from the client side and check from the server side too?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript's `Date` object records and tracks the time in UTC internally, but it accepts input and produces output in the local time on which it's running. It has very few facilities for working with time in other time zones.

You can use library [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) and then use the function

```
var timeDifference = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
```

to calculate the timezone difference of client from UTC.

Or, you can use

```
var timeZone = moment.tz.guess();
```

It will return an IANA time zone identifier, such as America/Los_Angeles for the US Pacific time zone.

[image]

This is one of the picture from moment.js website where you can see the way to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your function and it works the way it should, ie, return true if it's M-F, 8-5 in JKT and false if it's not.

I can think of two possible problems:
 1. There's a problem with the function calling checkDateTime and returning "Available" or "Not Available"
 2. Your server is not set to the current date and time, and therefore even if you convert the datetime to JKT timezone, your function will not return the expected output.